# DATEADD FUNCTION SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select data from `1st jan 2017` till `31 dec 2018` .

I have a query where I have used 
`BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(year,1,GETDATE())` but I'm getting data only from `october 2017` till `jan 2019`. 
How can I achieve that? Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `datediff()`:

```
where datediff(year, datecol, getdate()) <= 1
```

A more obvious method is to do explicit date comparisons:

```
where datecol >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1) and
      datecol < datefromparts(year(getdate()) + 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: thats really helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use this:

```
between DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
and     DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)
```

It states where the date is between the first of the previous year and the last date of the current year so Eg. `1st jan 2017 till 31 dec 2018`

You were getting the wrong dates because getdate() is the current date so when you do -1 year it is starting from today which would be `25 October 2018` and then saying -1 = `25 October 2017`. Same with the other dateadd.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it very simply like below,

```
select * from table_name WHERE (date_column BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2019-01-01')
```

or you can also use datepart for specific year selection

```
select * from table_name where datepart(YYYY,date_column) >=2017 and datepart(YYYY,date_column) <=2019
```